# How to clean the list of previous "command line" in execute maven goal window of intellij ce

Tags: java, configuration, intellij-idea, ide, maven-3

IntelliJ CE is great integrating maven execution for modules.

Im using IntelliJ CE 13, and for custom maven executions i'm using the "Execute maven goal" window.
[image]

A great feature it has is it remembers all (and i mean *all*) of the previous executions, which is a great thing to avoid typing over and over the same command.

BUT, if anytime you type a really long command, the window gets resized to fit in the command, so it's a little bit annoying to scroll in order to view the "choose module" button.

Is there any way of "cleaning" that list of previous executions???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is not a way via the UI to clear that list. You may want to open a feature request to do such: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

That said, there is a hack you can do to clear it (or selective items).

1. Close your project
2. Go to the `.idea` directory within your project

   - if you are using file based project and not directory based project settings, you can search the `.iws` file for the following
3. Backup the `workspace.xml` file
4. Open the `workspace.xml` file
5. Do a search for `<component name="mavenExecuteGoalHistory">`

   - It's path is: `/project/component[@name='mavenExecuteGoalHistory']`
6. Delete any or all of the `<option>` elements within that `<component>` element
7. Save the file and reopen your project.

Comment: thank you!! it worked like a charm :) and it actually would be a great feature to have it from the UI

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution to this problem since the I didn't get the suggested answer to work. There is a way to access a context menu where a delete option is available.
By highlighting your project folder and navigating to the top menu "Run"->"Run Maven Goal", you will be directed to the mentioned context menu.
This works on Intellij IDEA 2020.3.1
[Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSs2B.png)